# How to set the current state to the useState hook?

Tags: reactjs

I have a state to keep track when a SubMenu is opened, and toggle it when another Menu Item is clicked. It goes like this:

```
    const [open, setOpen] = useState();
    const toggle = (id) => setOpen(id);

    onClick={() => toggle(item.navId)}
```

When I click the refresh button in the browser, the current Sub Menu that is opened, closes. I believe it is because the initial state is empty. How can I keep the current Sub Menu opened after the page is reloaded/refreshed. I've been looking around and I am really not sure if I should use `prevState` or how to implement it to my case. Any tips or pointing a direction to a solution is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: store the selected value in `localStorage`

Comment: Either that or store the state of the drawer in a parent component.

Comment: @DerekWilliams Wouldn't parent also lose the data when browser is refreshed

Comment: Would that be the case to use the `useLocalStorage` hook? Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to persist the data when the browser is refreshed. As others stated using LocalStorage is a good option. I always use a custom hook I wrote for such cases:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export function useLocalStorage(key, defaultValue) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    const valueInLocalStorage = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (valueInLocalStorage) {
      return JSON.parse(valueInLocalStorage);
    }
    return defaultValue;
  });

  const prevKeyRef = useRef(key);

  useEffect(() => {
    const prevKey = prevKeyRef.current;
    if (prevKey !== key) {
      window.localStorage.removeItem(prevKey);
    }
    prevKeyRef.current = key;
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [key, state]);

  return [state, setState];
}
```

You can then import it and use it

```
import { useLocalStorage } from 'hooks/uselocalStorage';
const [open, setOpen] = useLocalStorage(storageKey, initialConfig);
```

Comment: OMG! I don't think I'd ever be able to do it by my own with a custom hook like this. I will keep this hook forever. Thanks ever so much. It worked like a charm. I really appreciate sharing such a nice stuff. Cheers.

Comment: Don't worry, it's all about learning and experience, we all do research and learn in the process :) good luck to you! and happy I could help

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the refresh button of the browser, your state will take its initial value, `null` in your case because you are not passing anything. `prevState` will have the same behavior. `localStorage` can be a solution:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(localStorage.getItem("open"));
  const toggle = (id) => {
    setOpen(id);
    localStorage.setItem("open", id);
  };

  // ...
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add a query parameter for the opened sub menu. URL might look something like this: `www.test.com/menu?nav=1`. Then you could read the value of  `nav` and use that for the initial state.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try it and the other methods.

Comment: this isnt the correct way to achieve this using react.